# Links not working

Tags: internet-explorer

When I click a `target=_blank`[1] link IE11 opens a new blank tab, rather than the expected tab. This works fine in Chrome[2] but fails in IE8, and now in IE 11.

I reset my browser settings (Internet settings/Advanced tab) and upgraded to IE 11 in an attempt to resolve this.

Changing the tab settings does seem to affect this, but no option gets the expected behaviour.

[1] example code:

```
<A class=oLinkExternal href="http://orgintranet.org.co.uk/systems/ibd-db/" target=_blank>IBD database</A>
```

[2]  Version 42.0.2311.135

Comment: Does it work if you change the link to `<a class="oLinkExternal" href="http://orgintranet.org.co.uk/systems/ibd-db/" target="_blank">IBD database</a>`? What if you omit the target?

Comment: It works without the _blank  but I can't remove that from every page on the Internet

Comment: In the web I found that a defunct OLEAUT32.dll' could be the reason. Can you re-install that from the original CD or another system?

Comment: Why that DLL? I just freshly updated from IE8 to IE11 so I believe it is config not code.

Answer (score 4):

Since `target="_blank"` works but not `target=_blank`, this looks like a bug
in IE11, not correctly parsing an attribute that starts with an underscore.

The workarounds for such a bug that I can think of are :

1. Use another and better browser
2. Fix every page on the Internet, replacing `target=_blank` with `target="_blank"`

For the first option you don't need my help.

The second option is not as impossible as it sounds.
I will outline below an approach, but you should take into account that
I don't use IE11 and have never tried this.

A software that modifies loaded HTML pages is [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey).
Some adaptations of it (of unknown quality) exist for IE11 :

- [GreasemonkIE](http://greasemonkie.com/)
- [TrixIE WPF4.5 beta](http://sourceforge.net/projects/trixiewpf45/)

Assuming that one of them works, here is a userscript that might do the job :

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        your-choice
// @namespace       http://avoid.collusions.com
// @description     Resets target="_blank" links hoping to add quotes.
// @include     *
// ==/UserScript==
(function () {
    var external = document.links; 
    for (var k=0; k<external.length; k++)   
        if (external[k].href && external[k].target=="_blank") 
            external[k].target = "_blank";
})();
```

This assumes, perhaps erroneously, that Greasemonkey will add quotes
around attributes that it replaces. If that doesn't happen,
the script can be modified to force the quotes.

As I have tested nothing, I apologize in advance if this approach doesn't work.

Comment: Nice answer but not correct. The issue occurs on IE8 on the same machine, but only that machine. I believe this is a configuration issue.

Comment: Try: (1) [sfc /scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html), (2) run `Internet Explorer (no Add-ons)` ([more info](http://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/simple-how-tos/164-run-internet-explorer-in-safe-mode-without-add-ons)), (3) disable [Enhanced Protected Mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/03/14/enhanced-protected-mode.aspx) if it's on, (4) try both the [32-bit and 64-bit versions of Internet Explorer](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-enable-64-bit-internet-explorer-processes/), (5) try booting into Safe mode. Report each result.

Comment: Also note that it's possible for IE8 & IE11 to be using a common system component.

Comment: If the problem occurs on a specific computer, but not others, then the problem is probably **on** that computer. Repair or reinstall the OS (as suggested by @harrymc) then try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the target='_blank' attrib using jQuery

something like

```
$document.ready(function(){
 $("a").attr('target','_blank');
});
```

or just js

```
var as = [].slice.apply(document.getElementsByClassName('oLinkExternal'));
for (var a in as){as[a].target="");}
```